Lottie - How to import animation using JSON?
Lottie has the ability to import images and sounds via URL in json. Is there a way to import external animations or shapes via URL in a json file?
There is an idea to use a data source asset for these purposes. But I couldn't achieve the desired behavior in the lottie editor. I couldn't find any examples of using data source assets in the documentation.
